# What is the difference between SeedSequence.spawn and SeedSequence.generate_state

Tags: numpy, random

I am trying to use numpy's [`SeedSequence`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.SeedSequence.html) to seed RNGs in different processes. However I am not sure whether I should use `ss.generate_state` or `ss.spawn`:

```
import concurrent.futures

import numpy as np


def worker(seed):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
    return rng.random(1)


num_repeats = 1000

ss = np.random.SeedSequence(243799254704924441050048792905230269161)
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    result1 = np.hstack(list(pool.map(worker, ss.generate_state(num_repeats))))

ss = np.random.SeedSequence(243799254704924441050048792905230269161)
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    result2 = np.hstack(list(pool.map(worker, ss.spawn(num_repeats))))
```

What are the differences between the two approaches and which should I use?

Using `ss.generate_state` is ~10% faster for the basic example above, likely because we are serializing floats instead of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `SeedSequence` is intended to generate good quality seeds from not so good seeds.

#### Performance

The `generate_state` is much faster than `spawn`

The difference of time for transfering the object or the state should not be the main reason for the difference you notice. You can test this without any

```py
%%timeit
ss.generate_state(num_repeats)
```

100 times faster than

```py
ss.spawn(num_repeats)
```

#### Seed size

In the code `map(worker, ss.generate_state(num_repeats))` the RNGs are seeded with integers, while in the `map(worker, ss.spawn(num_repeats))` the RNGs are seeded with `SeedSequence` that can potentially give result in quality initialization, the seed sequence can be used internally to generate a state vector with as many bits as required to completely initialize the RNG. Well, to be honest I expect it to do some expansion on this number to initialize the RNG, not simply padding with zeros for example.

#### Repeated use

The most important difference is that `generate_state` gives the same result if called multiple times. On the other hand, `spawn` gives different results each call.

For illustration, check the following example

```py
ss = np.random.SeedSequence(243799254704924441050048792905230269161)
print('With generate_state')
print(np.hstack([worker(s) for s in ss.generate_state(5)]))
print(np.hstack([worker(s) for s in ss.generate_state(5)]))
print('With spawn')
print(np.hstack([worker(s) for s in ss.spawn(5)]))
print(np.hstack([worker(s) for s in ss.spawn(5)]))
```

```txt
With generate_state
[0.6625651  0.17654256 0.25323331 0.38250588 0.52670541]
[0.6625651  0.17654256 0.25323331 0.38250588 0.52670541]
With spawn
[0.06988312 0.40886412 0.55733136 0.43249601 0.53394111]
[0.64885573 0.16788206 0.12435154 0.14676836 0.51876499]
```

As you see the arrays generated by seeding different RNGs with `generate_state`  gives the same result, not only immediately after construction, but every time the method is called. Spawn should give you the same results using a newly constructed `SeedSequence` (I am using numpy 1.19.2), however if you run the same code twice using the same instance, the second time will give produce different seeds.